# Comparing Fractions with Bool

Tags: java, boolean, fractions

So Im having a problem with my equals class

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other.equals(this.numerator) &&  other.equals(this.denominator))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

it gives me the result of 9/2 eq 9/2= false.

(Rest of my code for referees )
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6604f427cc9d17391478

What am i doing wrong?

I edited the code but still and dealing with an error of boolean and int

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other.equals(this.numerator) == getNumerator() &&  other.equals(this.denominator)== getDenominator())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the `Java`  tag

Comment: Your logic is incorrect since you should be checking the numerator of the other object with the numerator of this object and the denominator of the other object with denominator of this object. Currently, you are checking equality of the other object with denominator and numerator of this object which will always give you false.

Comment: Hey Jay! I tried changing it up a bit (Im still a beginner) and got   'public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other.equals(this.numerator) == getNumerator() &&  other.equals(this.denominator)== getDenominator())
     return true;
    else
     return false;
    }'

Comment: You also don't simplify fractions, so your program thinks `4/2` and `2/1` are different fractions.

Comment: Yeah im not sure why its nor reducing it everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing `equals`, before checking if the objects are equal you should consider the next scenarios:

- The two are actually references to the same object
- The `other` object is `null`
- The `other` object is an instance of a different type

and when checking equality between the two objects you should consider the *`nullness`* of every field involved in the comparison too. In most IDEs `equals` can be generated automatically, in eclipse:

> Alt + Shift + s --> Generate hashCode() and equals()

the next is generated by eclipse:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        A other = (A) obj;
        if (denominator == null) {
            if (other.denominator != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!denominator.equals(other.denominator))
            return false;
        if (numerator == null) {
            if (other.numerator != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!numerator.equals(other.numerator))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return
    (other.numerator.equals(this.numerator)
    && 
    other.denominator.equals(this.denominator))
```

Of couse this doesn't consider that 1/2 == 2/4.